# Operators and quote precedence in obfuscated cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd, obfuscation, deobfuscation

Im having trouble understanding how this will evaluate, it comes from a piece of malware I'm dissecting, so beware.

I've removed the ascii giberish and the integers in the foor loop which is likely to have the malicious instructions. So it should be fine, I can provide it if need be.

If i strip down the code the most my basic understanding allows, it is trying to pass this:

```
cmd.exe /c CmD /V/C"set foo=ASCIIgibberish bazz=moreASCIIgibberish&&for %f in (BunchOfIntegers)do set bar=!bar!!foo:~%f,1!&&if %f == 88 powershell.exe "!bar:~6!""
```

To:

```
Interaction.Shell(`here`,0)
```

So, I am not sure how cmd and powershell would resolve the quotes or variable names since I'm not really familiarized with powershell and cmd precedence.

What i would like to know is

would cmd interpret the `!` as a logical not?

if so, how does cmd or powershell evaluate the negation of a literal value?, I want to assume it sees the ascii value and logically negates it, (0001 becomes 1110) but not sure.

Am I correct in assuming that this is just an obfuscated way of saying `powershell.exe barSubstringStartingAt6`, because as I see it `bar` is only being assigned character 88 from `foo` which is 79 chars long, so is not possible to know what would be at `bar`[6].

Are they just trying to send an overflowed address to powershell?

Comment: `!var!` is a reference to the value inside the variable using *delayed expansion* syntax. The code is reordering (or decoding) *ASCIIgibberish* using *BunchOfIntegers* as order indexes into *ASCIIgibberish*. When the integer is *88* the resulting string (from position 6) is passed to powershell.

Comment: `set bar=!bar!!foo:~%f,1!` is building up a string in the `bar` variable that is one character from the `foo` variable at the integer index in the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kindly explained by @MC ND and @lit, `!var!` is not a logical operator but rather shorthand for delayed expansion syntax. Therefore the statement is just rearranging characters within the variable by using the int within the for loop as an index