# How does cmd lays out variables in memory

Tags: memory, cmd, deobfuscation

How does cmd lays out the variables in memory for this declaration?:

```
set foo=ASCIIchars bar=moreASCIIchars
```

Im trying to deobfuscate [this kind of malware code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748995/operators-and-quote-precedence-in-obfuscated-cmd/). I was able to successfully read most of the malicious code, except for the characters that would correspond to the space between the vars.

For the particular case im working, for the first two variables, it lays out the memory like `ASCIIchars???moreASCIIchars` in this case, each `?` is an unknown character which I assume is padding to complete a 4 byte word.

I would like to know if that padding is random or specifically assigned, might be related to the second variable name but not sure.

Comment: If it helps, SET only sets one variable at a time. So, `bar=` is just part of the value that `foo` is being set to (unless your `ASCIIchars` contains characters that are interpreted as ending of the value for SET, making the rest part of another command.) See also `SET /?` and `cmd /?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I´m not sure if I understand this particularly question, but, that is my point:

```bat
@echo/ may by is not 2 variable, but ony one? & set "'=ASCIIchars bar=moreASCIIchars" & echo/%'%
```

Results:

```bat
 may by is not 2 variable, but ony one?
  ASCIIchars bar=moreASCIIchars
```

[[image: Results[1]]

I´m need set some time space, equal, and another character "special", and i use this little tricks,

**1)** put **"** inside comma **"**

**2)** set name to the variable = **'**

If you get this information (I not know how)**above** replicated, I presume that string is one variable.

> ASCIIchars???moreASCIIchars

So, I hope this can be helpful to your valuable activities!

Comment: Thank you, as @Tom Blodget explained, `set` will only set a variable at a time, so in this case the command was trying to set a string containing giberish which included a space and an equal sign, which at first glance seemed like a second variable.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that in this particular case, the obfuscation script was trying to use the space and equal sign as well, not sure why or how, but I assume that it has to do with the fact that ends ith a slash`/` before adding another command using `&&`

So, for:

```
set foo=ASCIIchars bar=moreASCIIchars/&&
```

The memory for `foo`gets laid out exactly as stated in ascii: `ASCIIchars bar=moreASCIIchars/` it might have something to do with how cmd resolves quotes, you can find the [malware structure here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748995/operators-and-quote-precedence-in-obfuscated-cmd/), glad to announce that I deobfuscated the malware which intended to download files using powershell